# How to set screensaver thumbnail in Settings panel on Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, screensaver

I'm making a custom *.saver application, and I would like to add my own thumbnail to show up above the name of screensaver (the ladybug pictures in the left column). How do I do that?

[image: Screensaver]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By examining the default screensavers, I figured out that you need to add two files:

```
thumbnail.png, 58x90px
thumbnail@2x.png, 116x180px
```

When compiled by Xcode, this is automatically included in the .saver Resources folder as "thumbnail.tiff" with two subfiles.

Comment: Thank you for this! Small correction: the thumbnail images should be landscape, so 90x58 and 180x116.

Comment: Add two files where? In which directory?

Comment: Wasn't sure where to add this. Just want to confirm to anyone else looking to just add them to the root of the xcode project, and on build they'll show up as thumbnails.

Comment: Whilst images of these sizes work, they no longer look correct as they have a strange outline.